# Авторизация по ключу SSH без пароля

Tags: ssh-key, ssh, linux

Есть необходимость авторизации в линуксе по ключу SSH. Сделал ключи (публичный и приватный). Публичный скопировал в: `/home/eugene/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Что в файле (одной строкой):

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAjqa1EnAnrlEx5NS6py6SmsQzAWpw8/7suyAa
> mPMr16yMX1BZfyzO7LFA/6MRvJ4dCRxnhJNJD2IW/FGZGg5iJNndw+42HuDkiPEX
> VcX2XYk9yXUAYX5xqR9zzdafsDZsekelsGATibBWa8iJi4RiW3xozDzKdobM9n17
> Ok2rAMk=

В файле конфигурации SSH:

> Port 22
> Protocol 2
> RSAAuthentication yes
> PubkeyAuthentication yes
> AuthorizedKeysFile      ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Всё писать не стал. Это вроде как основное. Если что, поправьте.

Вхожу через путти с приватным ключём, и пишет в ответ:

> Server refused our key

Пробовал и другие клиенты. Всё равно то же самое.

**Добавление.**

> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "eugene"`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "*-*-191-67.*.ua"`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: Failed none for eugene from *.*.191.67 port 59873 s  sh2`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/  blacklis  t.RSA-1024`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-  1024`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: Could not open keyfile '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: Could not open keyfile '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: Failed publickey for eugene from *.*.191.67 port 59873 ssh2`

Comment: С паролем войти можете на сервер?

Comment: С паролем да, заходит.
Но с паролем хочу отключить авторизацию. Лучше на ключ сделаю пароль.

Comment: Сгенерируйте ключи при помощи утилиты из состава PuTTY

Comment: Не видно тут два последних ответа, что пришли на почту.      

Ключи делал через путти. Но дело не в ключе. Что-то в конфиге ssh. А где можно посмотреть логи ssh? Установлен Дебиан, если что.

Comment: Какая система у Вас? Попробуйте посмотреть в /var/log/secure и сгенерьте ключи через ssh-keygen, а не putty

Comment: Дело не в генераторе ключей. Разными способами пробовали.

Comment: Чтобы ответы не терялись, пишете мне на почту, указана в профайле. Что в логах?

Comment: Система Дебиан.  
/var/log/auth.log

ssh-keygenMar 15 17:27:49 ht-5 sshd[16514]: Accepted password for eugene from 188.115.19$
Mar 15 17:27:49 ht-5 sshd[16514]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user eugene$

В файле /var/log/secure ничего не записывается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос. оказывается надо было в файле конфигурации написать:

> AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

вместо:

> AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 3):

Если можно попасть с паролем, то есть смысл глянуть логи, почему sshd отбивает авторизацию по ключу. В конфиге sshd можно также включить DEGUB логирование.

Делаем так.

1) Включаем дебаг лог для sshd:

```
# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG
```

и ребутаем sshd.

2) Подключаемся к серверу по ssh с паролем. И ставим лог на отслеживание:

```
- tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

3) Второй сессией пытаемся подключиться с ключём и в режиме реального времени смотрим, что пишется в лог.

**Добавление.**

Все верно.

Вот ошибки:

> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: Could not open keyfile '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: trying public key file  /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
> `Mar 15 18:04:20 ht-5 sshd[16966]: debug1: Could not open keyfile '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied`

Permission denied

Comment: icq 250460610

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку по поводу логов. Если подключаться от имено рута, то ключ проходит. Если пользователя другой - пишет уже те ошибки, что указывал выше.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так, а публичный ключ лежит не в `root`, а в `eugene` в домашнем каталоге.

Comment: Так а разве он должен быть у рута, если я авторизуюсь через другого пользователя?

Comment: Он должен лежать у пользователя, но для этого надо как-то корректно в PuTTY указать имя пользователя, которым логинитесь. Я пользуюсь bitwiser (или что-то в этом роде - точное название не помню), поэтому как в puTTY указать имя для логина через ключи не представляю.

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема была, было всё из за прав на папку пользователя и ключа. Вот так работает.

> `user@85.25.109.91  вот так в putty задаётся user
> drwx------ 2 user  user   4096     Dec 22 13:06       .ssh        такие права на папку
> Конфиг по умолчания 
> Строку не раскрывал
> \#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`